# Equation of a curve between two points whereas the curve limits are defined by the two points

Tags: python, math, pygame

I've been trying to find a way in python to calculate an equation of a curved line that intersects the axis of their respective points at exactly 90 degrees whereas the curve does not exceed the y-value of the first point and the x-value of the second point. As a visual, I'm trying to write some code that creates an equation for a line like this one:

[image]

Is there anyway that something like this would be possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, an ellipse with center at the origin and ends of the major and minor axes at your given points on the x and y axes would do it. If the point on the x-axis has the x-coordinate `a` and the point on the y-axis has the y-coordinate `b` than an equation is

```
x**2/a**2 + y**2/b**2 == 1
```

If you want a functional equation that calculates the y-value from the x-value,

```
y = b * math.sqrt(1 - (x / a) ** 2)
```

which works for `0 <= x <= a`.

Another way to get the graph that is more smooth near `x==a` is this parameterization for `0 <= t <= math.pi / 2`:

```
x = a * math.cos(t)
y = b * math.sin(t)
```

Another, somewhat more flexible solution is to use a Bezier curve rather than an ellipse, but that is more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I believe this is exactly what I need. Thanks!